# How to delete rows depending on more than 1 column conditions

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with 12 columns, and i want to delete rows that have 0 value at columns 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and 12 at the same time.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work:

```
cat Combined_PromoterAnalysis.bed |\
 awk -F "" '{ if ($4==0,$5==0,$6==0,$7==0,$8==0,$9==0,$10==0,$11==0,$12==0)  print $0 }' > Modified.bed
```

Comment: I'm curious - what language are you thinking of that uses `,` for the conditional `and` operator? Have you ever used an Algol-based language like C, C++, Pascal, or Ada? What do THEY use for the `and` operator? You wrote `if (condition) print $0` - what do you think will happen when `condition` is true - that the current record will be printed or that it will not be printed? Which did you want to happen? What do you think you'd need to change in your script to do the opposite? Also, google UUOC. Post sample input and expected output for more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that everything is true. For this, you need to say `condition1 && condition2 ...`.

This will print all those lines in which at least one of these files is not 0:

```
awk -F "" '!($4==0 && $5==0 && $6==0 && $7==0 && $8==0 && $9==0 && $10==0 && $11==0 && $12==0)' file
```

However, it may be better to loop through these fields and print the line whenever one of them is not `0`:

```
awk '{for (i=4;i<=12;i++) if ($i!=0) {print; next}}' file
```

Can the values be negative? Because if they are all positive you can check if the sum is `0`:

```
awk -F "" '$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12' file
```